# Retrieving dates and links with Rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

Dear fellow programers,

i have following questions. when i try to extract information from html with Rvest, dates and links disappear.

HTML is the following

```
string <- "<table class='\\\"wrapped\\\"'>\n<colgroup>\n<col>\n<col>\n</colgroup>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<th>Date</th>\n<th>Finding List</th>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan='\\\"1\\\"'><div class='\\\"content-wrapper\\\"'><p><time datetime='\\\"2021-01-04\\\"'></time> </p></div></td>\n<td colspan='\\\"1\\\"'><div class='\\\"content-wrapper\\\"'><p><link></p></div></td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n"
```

but if i use the following code

```
html_table(string ,fill=T)
```

it will return column names but not the values below.

I was expecting a table with column names and values "2021-01-04" and link

Comment: The `html_table` function extracts the text located in table cells. It ignore additional tags. Your example table does not contain text, it only contains tags and attributes with values.

Comment: Hi, actually there is value 2021-01-04

Comment: Well, there is a `<time>` element with `datetime` attribute (with some funky quoting mixed in): `<p><time datetime='\"2021-01-04\"'></time></p> `, so you probably have to handle table structure yourself if you need to extract attributes, i.e  `minimal_html(string) |> html_elements("tr td p time") |> html_attr("datetime")`